# vba code to find a blank reord hanging up

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access database that I have employer information. Such as name, address, phone number, contact person, business type, etc. There are multiple people entering data & occasionally there is a blank record, because there was an entry started & not finished.

I am trying to use VBA to find the blank record, so I can enter new data in the blank record. Here is the current code.

```
Private Sub Command107_Click()

If DCount("*", "Blank Query") = "0" Then
    MsgBox ("No blank records found. Thank You!")
Else
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , [Queries]![Blank Query2], offset:=1
End If

End Sub
```

Currently if there is a blank record it hangs on

> DoCmd.GoToRecord , , [Queries]![Blank Query2], offset:=1

If there is no blank records, it runs & give the appropriate response. 
The only field I am concerned about is, name and address. 
Ideally, I would like to have it go to the blank record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
  Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strSQL  As String

  strSQL = "select * from tblContacts where " & _
           "IsNull([Name]) or IsNull(Address)"
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
     Me.Recordset.FindFirst "id = " & rst!ID
  Else
     MsgBox "no blank reocrds found"
  End If

  rst.Close
```

Comment: I had to modify it a little to get it to run. I found that Address needed  [ ], & I had to delete address. here is the working code `Private Sub Command107_Click()

 Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strSQL  As String

  strSQL = "select * from Employer_List_Table where " & _
           "IsNull([Business Name])"
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
     Me.Recordset.FindFirst "id = " & rst!ID
  Else
     MsgBox "no blank reocrds found"
  End If

  rst.Close
End Sub`

Comment: The only thing I added to give the user a audio indication of the result was this piece of code: `Interaction.Beep` It is placed after `Else` & before `MsgBox`

Answer (score 0):

DoCmd.GoToRecord will only work if your form is based on your query [Blank Query2]. 
Apart from that, your syntaxis is incorrect, referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194117.aspx

If this issue occurs on a regular basis, I'd create a form based on [Blank Query2] and add this form to your maintenance / application management frontend (assuming you've split your database into a backend and frontend).

Comment: It is based on [Blank Query2]. The database is split into front & backend & it is added to the maintenance / application management frontend. When I go to the query it does show the correct record.

Comment: If you already have a form based on a query that retrieves all records that should be modified, what would you need VBA for? You can navigate through all the records in your form and adjust them.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the ID of the first incomplete Record

```
 RecordID=Nz(DLookup("TablePrimaryKey","TableName","FieldThatCouldBEEmpty IS NULL"),0)
```

assuming your table has a proper Primary Key. If it does not you can request any field that would help you identify the record, just be sure to change 0 to an appropriate "no record found" value for whatever field you are looking up.

This will just delete any reocrds that are incomplete.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE FieldThatCouldBEEmpty IS NULL"
```